# I want to retrieve all the users and their properties individually, so i can use them for displaying in a neat list

Tags: php, html, css, curl, intercom

When I run it returns a list of all users. I dont know how to seperate them. I already checked https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#list-users but it didn't really help.

I haven't really tried anything yet since i dont even know where to start.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.intercom.io/users");

$headers = [
    'Authorization:Bearer key',
    'Accept: application/json',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

It returns

> "pages":{"type":"pages","next":null,"page":1,"per_page":50,"total_pages":1},"total_count":7,"limited":false,"type":"user.list","users":[{"type":"user","id":"5d8b1a7422b912ea9149d7b0","user_id":"42069","anonymous":false,"email":"xdxd@mynamejeff.nl","phone":"2112321","name":"Jeff","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"xco2b8a7","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":

It returns this for every user (so just imagine this x10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$server_output` is being populated with data ( as you have stated is the case ) then perhaps this ought to help.

```
$json=json_decode( $server_output );
$users=$json->users;

foreach( $users as $user ){
    $type=$user->type;
    $id=$user->id;
    $email=$user->email;
    $name=$user->name;
    /* etc etc */

    printf('
    <pre>
    ID:%s
    Type:%s
    Name:%s
    Email:%s
    </pre>',$id,$type,$name,$email);
}
```

Example output from the above:

```
ID:5d8b17e44b56e3bf87bf6128
Type:user
Name:Geronimo Bogtrotter
Email:geronimo@littlebighorn.com

ID:5d8b16b2558d909c887b7b16
Type:user
Name:Roland TB303
Email:roland@acid.com
```

There are considerably more properties available for each user - I guess it depends upon your requirements as to which fields have been populated - you, or someone in your company, presumably added users?!

Comment: that gives me the error **"Notice: Trying to get property 'users' of non-object in"**

Comment: can you add a sample of the response you get in `$server_output` because your question is a little devoid of content so far and is likely to get closed as a result

Comment: yeah i realised that

Comment: did you get your code to work using the method I showed?